# Converting Datetime to SQL UTC

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, utc

I have a work task to update some StartDateUtc and EndDateUtc fields in the SQL database.

The Customer service person gave me the unique item Id to update (yay!)
and the date it should be. Problem is, he gave me the dates in the following format:

- June 4th, 2015 9pm - 10pm
- May 3rd, 2015 8am - 1pm
- December 1st, 2015 3pm - 8pm

I need to somehow convert these dates to the SQL format (2007-05-04 01:34:11.933) easily.

Is there some built-in SQL or .NET method i don't know about that can do this easily? Or better yet, a website that allows me to put in a date in a datepicker and it spits out the SQL format (that would be ideal)

Comment: UTC relates to time zone, not the format the date is presented in.

Comment: SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentTime, GETUTCDATE() AS UTCTime try this

Comment: How many of these values are there?

Comment: There are only 20 or so.

Comment: Why not just do it by hand? It would take maybe 10 minutes. '2015-06-04 21:00:00' for Jun4 th, 2015

Comment: I was trying to learn something new @SeanLange ^__^

Comment: Well you can do something like this. select CONVERT(datetime, 'June 4, 2015 9pm') Notice you would have to remove the "th" and also remove the 10pm portion.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy function in SQL or .NET CLR to do what you want. Here's one way to do in pure SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertDate]
(
    @str    nvarchar(30)
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE 
(
    StartDate   datetime
,   EndDate     datetime
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ThirdWhitespace    int          = CHARINDEX(' ', @str, CHARINDEX(' ', @str, CHARINDEX(' ', @str) + 1) + 1)
    DECLARE @FourthWhitespace   int          = CHARINDEX(' ', @str, @ThirdWhitespace + 1)
    DECLARE @FifthWhitespace    int          = CHARINDEX(' ', @str, @FourthWhitespace + 1)
    DECLARE @FirstComma         int          = CHARINDEX(',', @str)

    DECLARE @DateString         nvarchar(30) = STUFF(LEFT(@str, @ThirdWhitespace), @FirstComma - 2, 2, '')
    DECLARE @StartTimeString    nvarchar(10) = SUBSTRING(@str, @ThirdWhitespace + 1, @FourthWhitespace - @ThirdWhitespace - 1)
    DECLARE @EndTimeString      nvarchar(10) = SUBSTRING(@str, @FifthWhitespace + 1, 100)

    INSERT INTO @Result
    SELECT  CAST(@DateString AS datetime) + CAST(@StartTimeString AS datetime)
        ,   CAST(@DateString AS datetime) + CAST(@EndTimeString   AS datetime)
    RETURN 
END
```

Usage:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        dbo.ConvertDate('May 3rd, 2015 8am - 1pm')
```

Note that this is very finicky. If you add an extra space anywhere in the string, it will break. If you have .NET CLR at your disposal, you can use regex to capture the components.